# Views Export button to block

Tags: views, blocks

I have a view with `Data Export`, where it creates a button to download the view's content, depending on a filter supplied by URL query parameters. I'm able to edit the the button using `THEME_views_data_export_feed_icon` in my theme's `template.php`. That's all good and works as intended.

How can I create a Drupal 7 Block that behaves just as that export button? Is it best to manually create a php block picks up the page URL/query to set as the export block link, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you should have a path/url to your Data Export Views (second column, at the top, Data Export Settings > Path). So you just need to create a block with a link to this URL in its body and it will directly launch the export procedure (no filters considered though). You may add CSS/Bootstrap class to your link and here is your nice export button in a block, which you can add anywhere in your website.